# Codeigniter ajax form validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I achieved the ajax form validation. But even though all input types have values in it. It shows the `$this->form_validation->run()` `false`. I am not getting how to resolve this issue.

**Controller code**

---

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('balance', 'Balance', 'trim|required|numeric');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        echo validation_errors();


    }else{

    }
```

**AJAX call**

---

```
$('#updateUsersInfo').on('click',function(){


 $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url();?>admin/updateUserData",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'submit_token': $('#token_id').val()},
        success:function(data){

            $('#bindErrors').text(data);


        }

    }) ;
});
```

**View code**

---

```
<form class="popupform" method="post">
            <div class="error" id="bindErrors"></div>
                <div  id="bindSuccessMsg"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class = "col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            First name <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            Last name <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            Email <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" readonly placeholder="Email address" name="email_address" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            Balance <input type="number" id="balance" class="form-control" placeholder="Balance" name="balance" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="radio" >
                                <label style="margin-right: 10px;">
                                    <input type="radio"  name="account_type" value="1"  >Personal</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label><input type="radio"  name="account_type"  value="3">Business</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="clear:left; padding-top: 10px;">
                            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value=""/>

                            <input type="submit" id="updateUsersInfo" class="btn tf-btn btn-default" value="Submit"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

I have used CSRF token, But now in code don't consider that. apart from that can some one let me know why error shows up even though fields are with valid data.

I am using codeigniter 3.0.3

Comment: Refer: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/473386/codeigniter-and-form-validation-ajax

Comment: Are you add Form validation code in updateUserData method ?

Comment: @Vaira Muthu, Yes I have added in updateUserData, M loading library in the constructor.

Comment: Where are your post firstname and others to that function ?

Comment: @InsaneSkull, Yes I referred that, But not finding any difference. I have also done like that only.

Comment: Do one thing before that validation print all POST data and let me know, what you get and check for name.

Comment: @HarshSanghani,    [id] => 1002
    [data] => first_name=preetham&last_name=kp&email_address=kp.pritam.30%40gmail.com&balance=0&account_type=1&user_id=1002

Comment: That's mistake You got all data within data element, try $_POST['first_name'] and let me know .

Comment: I Got the answer, I was serializing the form data. so it was not showing in the post. Thanks.

Comment: Also use    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {

Answer (score 0):

In this line echo validation_errors();    what you have to do is 
echo json_encode(validation_errors()) because in ajax call you are using   dataType: 'json',  and success:function(data){ console.log(data); just try these things it will work